# Magento Drop-down-menu error

Tags: magento, drop-down-menu

I have a problem with my drop down menu on my magento website. My sub menus are always shown and not hidden until hover as was supposed to be. Can anyone help me resolve this issue? My website is: http://tinyurl.com/nh6vf4g 
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

div.navbar li.parent{position:relative}

div.navbar li.parent ul.shown-sub{position:absolute;top:40px;left:9px;z-index: 2000 !important;}

Comment: I put this code and it worked #nav ul, #nav div {
border: 1px solid #899BA5;
left: -10000px;
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
background-color:#fff;
width: 13em;
font-weight: bold;line-height: 30px;
font-size: 14px;
}#nav ul li a:hover {color:#066cc3;}
#nav li ul.shown-sub,
#nav li div.shown-sub { left:auto;height:auto; z-index:999; padding: 8px 8px;}